# Can't run Spring 3 based web application on WebSphere?

Tags: spring, websphere, introspection, spring-3

I have a web application which is based on Spring 3.1.1. It runs perfectly fine on Apache Tomcat 7.0. However, when I run it on, IBM WebSphere Application Server V7.0, I am receiving an error:

```
00000020 HiddenInputTa E org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag doStartTag Failed to obtain BeanInfo for class [com.bean.CustomBean]; nested exception is java.beans.IntrospectionException: Indexed read method is not compatible with indexed write method
    org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Failed to obtain BeanInfo for class [com.bean.CustomBean]; nested exception is java.beans.IntrospectionException: Indexed read method is not compatible with indexed write method
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.<init>(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:262)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:149)
    ...
```

I also checked the problem bean to see if there is a missing getter or setting but all attributes has its corresponding getters and setters. The problem bean extends another custom bean which implements Cloneable.

What could be the problem? How do I fix it? How do I run Spring 3.1.1. based web application on WebSphere?

Comment: can you post the problem Bean.

Comment: Which versions of java are you running? Is the WAS running on the IBM JVM?

Comment: Since it's talking about "indexed write", I'd suspect getter/setter methods for a collection or array property.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the exception I suspect one of the following:

- getter or setter missing
- getter or setter not spelled correctly i.e. not considered being getter/setter for field
- getter return type not equal setter parameter type

Comment: I'm interested to learn what the cause was, pls keep us posted.